Does the closure of product of two ideals satisfy $\overline{I_1I_2}=\overline{I_1}\ \overline{I_2}$.

Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$ algebra and $I_1$ and $I_2$ be two ideals in $A$. Is it true that $\overline{I_1I_2}=\overline{I_1}\  \overline{I_2}$?

It is clear that $\overline{I_1I_2} \supseteq \overline{I_1}\ \overline{I_2}$. I'm unable to prove the other part.

Are your ideals self-adjoint?

@Justdroppedin: No.

It suffices to show $\bar{I_1}\bar{I_2}$ is closed. Thus, it suffices to prove that, if $I_1, I_2 \subset A$ are two closed ideals, then $I_1I_2$ is closed. Recall that any closed ideal in a $C^\ast$-algebra is self-adjoint, whence a $C^\ast$-algebra in its own right. Let $a \in (I_1 \cap I_2)_+$. Then $a^{1/2} \in I_1 \cap I_2$, so $a = a^{1/2}a^{1/2} \in I_1I_2$. As a $C^\ast$-algebra is spanned by its positive elements, we have $I_1 \cap I_2 \subset I_1I_2$. Clearly, $I_1I_2 \subset I_1 \cap I_2$, so $I_1I_2 = I_1 \cap I_2$ is closed.

Note that while all closed ideals are self-adjoint, not all ideals need to be. For example, $(z) \subset C(\mathbb{D})$ is not self-adjoint, as otherwise $\bar{z} = g(z)z$ for some $g \in C(\mathbb{D})$, that is, $g(z) = \frac{\bar{z}}{z}$ whenever $z \neq 0$. But $\frac{\bar{z}}{z}$ does not converge as $z \to 0$, so no such $g$ exists.
